# How do I read records from Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

How do I read records using SQL from Azure Synapse Analytics?

I am sending JSON data into Azure Synapse Analytics. 
Everything is fine on the stream analytics side: I can see my data, I can use
`select GetType(event_data) FROM…`
and it tells me it is of type `Record`. I can use `Select event_data.<JSON_KEY> FROM…` and it will give me back the value at that key.

Once the data is inside the Synapse database, however, I cannot read the records anymore.

```sql
select event_data from dbo.events;
```

Returns:

```
event_data
Record
Record
Record
Record
Record
Record
Record
Record
```

If I run:

```sql
select GetType(event_data) from dbo.events;
```

It tells me:

```
Msg 104162, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'GetType' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Running:

```sql
select JSON_VALUE(event_data, '$') from dbo.events;
```

Results in:

```
Msg 13609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'R' is found at position 0
```

This indicates that it is trying to parse the word 'Record' as JSON rather than the data inside the record.

How do I read records?

Comment: TO get type of your column : SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'events' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'event_data'

Comment: The data type is varchar.
When I created the table I defined it as nvarchar(max)